# Am I delusional, or does JS RegExp support optional repetition bounds?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/\d{,5}/.test('')
```

I thought that was a thing, but apparently not. Why might a person think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that was a thing, but apparently not. Why might a person think so?

If you look real fast at it, it does trick you. But the implementation of the operator is incomplete and will fail.

The following range quantifier/operators are recognized:

```
{n}     Match the preceding exactly n times
{n,}    Match the preceding at least n times
{n,m}   Match the preceding at least n but not more than m times
{n,}?   Match the preceding at least n times, but as few times as possible.
{n,m}?  Match the preceding between n and m times, but as few times as possible.
```

With using the  operator you must set a `{n` range, everything following `,m}` is optional.

Examples of correctly using the quantifier/operator.

```
"12345".match(/\d{3}/);    // => matches '123'
"12345".match(/\d{5,}/);   // => matches '12345', FAILS on 1234
"12345".match(/\d{1,4}/);  // => matches '1234'
"12345".match(/\d{2,}?/);  // => matches '12'
"12345".match(/\d{2,4}?/); // => matches '12'
```

Answer (score 2):

The quantifier `{n1,n2}` *is* a valid JavaScript regular expression quantifier that will match n1 through n2 times, inclusive.

However, `{,n}` does *not* represent a quantifier as the minimum bound is required. See section [15.10.2.7 Quantifier](http://es5.github.io/#x15.10.2.7) for the grammar productions and rules.

The following all introduce a valid range quantifier:

```js
/\d{3,5}/.test('12')      // false
/\d{3,5}/.test('1234')    // true
/\d{3,5}/.test('123456')  // false
```

On the other hand, the following regular expression *doesn't* create a quantifier. Instead, the production is parsed as literal text without special meaning:

```
/a{,5}b/.test('a{,5}b')   // true, at least in Chrome and IE
```

Comment: I see, the maxbound is optional, which is what I was thinking of.